AWS End User Messaging OTP Feature
I'm trying to send OTP's and be able to validate it with the Pinpoint API.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/send-validate-otp.html
Example AWS CLI command: aws pinpoint send-otp-message --application-id 7353f53e6885409fa32d07cedexample --send-otp-message-request-parameters Channel=SMS,BrandName=ExampleCorp,CodeLength=5,ValidityPeriod=20,AllowedAttempts=5,OriginationIdentity=+18555550142,DestinationIdentity=+12065550007,ReferenceId=SampleReferenceId
But I can't use this API because I don't have a Pinpoint application ID, I requested a phone number through AWS End User Messaging. I thought AWS End User Messaging is part of Pinpoint and that I'm supposed to use their API ... but it seems they are treated as two different services.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/apireference_smsvoicev2/API_Operations.html
I don't see an option on their API for OTP Sending/Validation like the Pinpoint docs have.
Is there a tool to send OTP with AWS End User Messaging that I can't find? Am I supposed to be able to use this API from Pinpoint to send/validate OTPs?
